# R find one column same but other column duplicates

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, subset

I'm using R and trying to find rows in a dataframe with one column value different but other 4 column values same:

I.E.

```
rn c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6
1 t  a  b  c  d  e
2 f  a  b  c  d  g
3 t  1  2  3  4  5 
4 t  1  2  3  4  5 
5 t  1  2  3  4  5 
6 f  a  b  c  d  e 
7 f  a  b  c  d  e
8 t  a  b  c  d  e
```

So in this case only rows which:
1. have duplicate values in column c2-c5 
2. but also have different value in c1
will remain.

```
 rn c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6
 1  t  a  b  c  d  e
 2  f  a  b  c  d  g
 6  f  a  b  c  d  e 
 7  f  a  b  c  d  e
 8  t  a  b  c  d  e
```

Anyway to do so?

Thanks

Comment: It seems to me that your question comes down to rows which duplicate the first set of fixed rows and are different from their predecessors? Is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by the columns c2 to c5 (`names(df1)[3:6]`), `if` the `length` of the `unique` (`uniqueN`) elements of 'c1' is greater than 1, we subset the data.table (`.SD`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, if(uniqueN(c1)>1) .SD, c(names(df1)[3:6])][, names(df1), with= FALSE]
#   rn c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6
#1:  1  t  a  b  c  d  e
#2:  2  f  a  b  c  d  g
#3:  6  f  a  b  c  d  e
#4:  7  f  a  b  c  d  e
#5:  8  t  a  b  c  d  e
```

---

An equivalent option in `dplyr` is

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by_(.dots = names(df1)[3:6]) %>%
    filter(n_distinct(c1) > 1)
#     rn    c1    c2    c3    c4    c5    c6
#  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1     1     t     a     b     c     d     e
#2     2     f     a     b     c     d     g
#3     6     f     a     b     c     d     e
#4     7     f     a     b     c     d     e
#5     8     t     a     b     c     d     e
```